# What shell does os.system use in Python?

Tags: python

In Python, when I run a command with

```
os.system
```

what shell gets used?

Comment: `os.system('echo $SHELL')` calls default shell. And `chsh` utility sets default shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default it will run in the Bourne shell (that would be `/bin/sh`).

`os.system("/bin/bash \"echo 'Rincewind rules' \" ")` to use `bash` and have it echo "Rincewind rules".

Comment: And since Bourne Shell is sym-linked to use dash it uses dash :)