# How to redirect a command's output to file, when the command is via a wrapper's system call?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, redirect

I want to redirect both output and stderr to a log file.
Easy enough, right?

```
python3 /home/user/Utilities/gpu.py L1.py &> log_L1.py.txt &
```

However, when instead of calling the command directly I use a system call, I do not get the output and the stderr in the files, but rather they are returned to my screen, and the output files are not created.

staggered_runner.py:

```
import time
import os

scripts=['L1.py','L2.py','L3.py','L4.py','L3_2D.py','L4_2D.py']

waiting=1200

for s in scripts:
    command='python3 /home/user/Utilities/gpu.py '+s+' &> log_'+s+'.txt &'
    print (command)
    os.system (command)
    time.sleep(waiting)
```

Then I run

```
python3 staggered_runner.py
```

I expected to receive only the direct outputs of `staggered_runner.py`, that is, those of each run of `print (command)`, and have the rest directed to the to appropriate files.

How can I do this, while still using the wrapper?

Comment: I suspect the reason it doesn't behave as expected is that `os.system` uses `/bin/sh` - which doesn't understand `&>` as a redirection: see for example [What shell does os.system use in Python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976710/what-shell-does-os-system-use-in-python). However IMHO you should really be using [subprocess.popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) where you can set the command's output file explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess, sys, shlex

try:
    process = (subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
            shell=True, cwd="Pass desired directory in as string variable")

  stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

use the shlex to build your command, and subprocess to execute it in the command prompt.

subprocess.Popen Allows you to set the current working directory and set a pipe up for IPC.